# Kestrel SNI certificate choosing (SSL/TLS)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0, kestrel-http-server, ms-yarp

I have a YARP gateway which uses the following configuration:

```json
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://+:80"
    },
    "HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
      "Url": "https://+:443",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "/tls/bundle.crt",
        "KeyPath": "/tls/cert.key"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added a new website with a new domain and now another certificate needs to be used for that site. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sni-in-configuration) shows this config:

```json
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "MySniEndpoint": {
        "Url": "https://*",
        "SslProtocols": ["Tls11", "Tls12"],
        "Sni": {
          "a.example.org": {
            "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2",
            "SslProtocols": ["Tls11", "Tls12", "Tls13"],
            "Certificate": {
              "Subject": "<subject; required>",
              "Store": "<certificate store; required>",
            },
            "ClientCertificateMode" : "NoCertificate"
          },
          "*.example.org": {
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
              "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
            }
          },
          "*": {
            // At least one subproperty needs to exist per SNI section or it
            // cannot be discovered via IConfiguration
            "Protocols": "Http1",
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but is has nothing in common with my current config and I'm afraid I'm gonna mess it up. What is the correct configuration for this scenario:

Main website -> *.site-a.com [everything works]
New website -> site-b.com [I got the `.crt` and `.key` files]

Allow HTTP (80) traffics, they will be redirected with `app.UseHttpsRedirection()`. For HTTPS (443) traffics, if it's `site-b.com` use `b-bundle.crt` and `b-cert.key` files, for anything else (which currently means `site-a.com` and its subdomains use `bundle.crt` and `cert.key` files.

Comment: not sure how to slove this why not adding another section in the appsettings.json for the second website.  "Second": "put your stufffs here", and read it @Parsa99

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the SIN feature of kestrel to specify different certificate for different domains.

Son then you also need to  convert your `.crt` and `.key` files into `.pfx` files, which you can do using `Open SSl` or other tools.
Here is the possible configuration that might work for you as well.

```
“Kestrel” : {
  “Endpoints” : {
    “Http” : {
      “Url” : “http
          :  //+:80” }, “HttpsSni”: { “Url”: “https://+:443”, “Sni”: {
             //“*.site-a.com”: { “Certificate”: { “Path”: “/tls/bundle.pfx”,
             //“Password”: “<password for bundle.pfx>” } }, “site-b.com”: {
             //“Certificate”: { “Path”: “/tls/b-bundle.pfx”, “Password”:
             //“<password for b-bundle.pfx>” } } } } } }
```